# significance of ~ symbol in matlab function

Tags: matlab, function-handle

If I have a function a that accepts 2 parameters (double) in Matlab as follows

```
function [x,y] = a(z)
```

What does the symbol "~" do when the function is called with this handle as follows

```
[x,~,y] = a[10]
```

Thanks

Comment: In general, it means use the three-output version of the function, but ignore the second output argument . It's like `[x,temp,y] = a[10]`, but the variable `temp` is not even created. See [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html). But in your case, you don not seem to have a three-output version of the function, so you will get an error

Comment: As with anything, try `help ~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "~" symbol in matlab is logical NOT. So it's basically like ignoring that output/input. For example, if I have a line of code like this:

[out1,~,out3] = function(vargin);

the second output is not kept or stored anywhere for later use. For more info, type "help ~" in the command window.

Comment: I don't think there's a conceptual link between `~` used as "logical not" and used as "ignore output". I'd rather see it as two different meanings of the same symbol

Comment: Perhaps you are right, what I should have posted was this: ">> help ~
 ~   Logical not.
    ~A performs a logical not of input array A, and returns an array
    containing elements set to either logical 1 (TRUE) or logical 0 (FALSE).
    An element of the output array is set to 1 if A contains a zero value
    element at that same array location.  Otherwise, that element is set to
    0.
 
    B = not(A) is called for the syntax '~A' when A is an object.
 
    ~ can also be used to ignore input arguments in a function definition,
    and output arguments in a function call.  See "help punct"